# Tooltips not working on IE10

Tags: html, css, tooltip, internet-explorer-10

I want to show tooltips on parts of an image. I have this technique where it puts a invisible div on the image with absolute positioning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" >
</head>

<body>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <img src="http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/BMW-M2-lead.jpg"/>
        <div title="HELLO" style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; top:0; left:0;"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

but when I hover over, the tooltip does not show.

Does anyone know what's wrong? This same code works on chrome 59.

Thanks

Comment: That's funny; it behaves as you say when I paste the source into a HTML file, but it does work correctly when I make a fiddle out of it! You may want to look into that.

Comment: I suppose this is due to a IE specific feature, empty elements are totally transparent, almost like there was `pointer-events: none` set. Setting a background color and `opacity: 0` for the divs on the image should do the trick. jsFiddle probably uses some CSS normalizer, which might change the behavior of the transparent elements in IE.

Answer (score 1):

this code seems to be ok on Explorer, Chrome, Firefox and Edge.
img tag has a different behaviour of div tag in Explorer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:relative;">
            <img src="http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/BMW-M2-lead.jpg"/>
            <img style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; top:0; left:0; border-width: 0px;" src="javascript:void(0)" title="Test" alt="">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, the `title` attribute did the job for IE v10 ;)